# How can password_verify validate passwords without knowing salt and cost?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

The function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) in the new PHP password API checks if the password corresponds to the hash. The hash is generated by [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), that by default uses a random salt and a `cost = 10`.

I always thought (although I never studied it) that you have to store the salt inside the database and then when you want to verify the password, hash it with the given salt using the same cost. How can `password_verify()` check the password without knowing salt and cost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The string returned by `password_hash()` contains not only the hash, but also the algorithm, cost and salt.

Comment: ...that's a #$@% great idea... why no one had thought it before? I thought to store also a "password version", so if I changed the algorithm, people with "old hashes" were able to login anyway... but with this API there's no need to do all that stuff!

Comment: Yes, hopefully PHP developers will finally let `md5()` retire now.

Comment: @LucasMalor - This is not a new invention, PHP's function `crypt()` did it like this all the time, and this is the working function behind `password_hash()`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: yes, but no one had thought to add all the information you need to compare password with hash in the same output, without bending over backwards to make other db columns for algorithm, salt, cost... that you must handle for both input and output, and writing an homemade random salt generator. Probably someone had done this in his personal library, but a simple and strong common API is much more convenient (by the way, thank you very much for suggesting me this API :D ).

Comment: I have a doubt, Niels (Bohr? :D ) and @martinstoeckli: if all the informations are on the db (algorithm, cost and salt), where is the additional protection? I mean, the salt was introduced to make more hard to understand the plain text password. But if I know all the data that I need to pass to the hashing function, an hacker that accessed my db can know the plain text password using a brute force, he have only to use password_verify() inside a loop. Is it not better to store a part of the salt inside a PHP variable, or in another dedicated db?

Comment: If an attacker has made his way into your server and stole one of your databases, what makes you think the other database is unaccessable? Your webserver would need credentials to access your salt database, so if he gets into your webserver, he can get into your salt database too.

Comment: And whether the information is encapsulated in one column or spread across three columns is insignificant. If he got into your database, he's got all the tables. Putting cost, algorithm, hash and salt into dedicated columns just means the attacker has to pass more parameters in his brute force loop. He probably knows how to pass parameters into functions. ;-)

Comment: The point of salt and cost isn't to increase the amount of data the attacker needs to steal, but to slow down his bruteforcing. Salts forces you to bruteforce only one user's password at a time, because every user has different salts. Cost controls how much time it takes for each try. Cost is a brilliant way to make bruteforcing impractical.

Comment: I don't think it slows down nothing if he has a good rainbow table... read http://www.rhyous.com/2012/06/18/how-to-effectively-salt-a-password-stored-as-a-hash-in-a-database/ at the section "Publishing the salt in the database".

Comment: "As soon as a string is found matching the hash". What kind of an argument is this? He might as well say "Hiding your treasure a random place in Asia is not effective, because you can stop searching Asia as soon as you find the treasure."

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've also read an interesting blog entry of the  password_compat creator: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html Anyway I just proposed to him a sort of pepper technique: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/29

Comment: @LucasMalor - But yes, including all the necessary parameters into one output string is exactly what `crypt()` did a long time ago. To your other question: the salt fulfills its purpose, even when known to the attacker. If the salt is unique per password, then an attacker would have to build a rainbowtable for each password, and could not build one rainbowtable to get all passwords at once. Maybe you want to have a look at my tutorial about [storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Excellent slides!